# Pig: Exception in outputSchema

Tags: apache-pig, schema, udf

### I've defined my outputSchema as follow

```
public class Upper extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    public Schema outputSchema(Schema schema) {

       if(schema.size() < 2) {
            log.info("--------------------Expecting two inputs.------------------------");
             throw new RuntimeException("Expecting at least two inputs.");
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

When I am using this EvalFunc in my code as follow

```
gen = foreach data generate upper(*);
```

Pig is throwing exception

```
2016-12-08 14:57:58,743 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. NULL Schema
Failed to parse: NULL Schema
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:201)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1735)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1443)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:387)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:412)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:749)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
```

I am not sure, how pig sees this as null schema when I am passing the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem lies in the eval function itself. AS you can see from stacktrace your function wasn't even called. Could you provide full pig script? I'm pretty sure the problem lies above